# why FormData is empy in angular

Tags: javascript, form-data

I'm using angular to send a request to server to add a picture

but when I log the formData, formData doesn't have anything, I've checked, file exists, file is not empty file exists but it doesn't append to formData

this is typescript file to set file in formData

```
sendPicture(event: any) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('picture', file);
  console.log(formData);
}
```

and here's what displays in the browser

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try the following code for log `formData` logs.

```
sendPicture(event: any) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('picture', file);
  console.log(formData.get('picture'));
}
```